# Safe to use old well?

Tags: water, well

When I moved in the old owner told me there was another well in addition to the one the house uses. He said they drilled it and it didn't provide enough flow so they abandoned it and drilled a new one.

It looks like a metal pipe sticking out of the ground, about 6" diameter, open to the world.

I want to have a backup hand powered well, but I want to make sure I can use this well. I dropped a weight on a string and hit water about 32', the weight went down another foot or so before it stopped. When I pulled it up it stank. I'm pretty sure there is enough water down there for my use. I'm sure they wouldn't have given up until they drilled at least 200 feet.

Question: For 40 years of the well being open let leaves and debris in. Could that have ruined the well? I know I can pour bleach in but will that be enough? Could the well be too blocked up to use?

Comment: Can you raise a sample and get it tested?

Comment: A foot of stagnant water is sufficient for your use? If you pump out foot of water will it be replaced and at what rate? "I'm sure they wouldn't have given up until they drilled at least 200 feet." are you saying that you think there is 168 feet of debri in the well?

Comment: The well depth depends on where you live and the aquifer. In some areas drilling two deep can cause more problems. I would be concerned with a well that was not installed properly this can lead to contamination of your primary well even if they are located a good distance apart. I would bleach the well and pump it then after several days take a sample in for analysis.